# Possible mistake in a proof about order of numerical methods

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

Consider the following

[image]
[image]
[image]

I belive the given conditions are necessary but not sufficient. This is because if the second summing equation holds for $p+1$ as well, then the order must be $>p$. So I think we need to add the condition
$$
\sum_{l=0}^s l^{p+1} \rho_l \not =(p+1) \sum_{l=0}^s l^{p} \sigma_l.
$$
Am I correct in my assertion?

Comment: So you are asking if an order $(p+1)$ method is also (considered as) an order $p$ method?

Comment: I think that according to my definition it is not. I would like to know if with what I have been given, whether the statement in the proof is correct or not.

Comment: Well, as the order conditions for order $(p+1)$ contain those of order $p$, and $h^{p+1}\in O(h^p)$ (for $h\to 0$), it is usually understood that the order $p$ methods contain the order $(p+1)$ methods. If an ODE function is not suitable for order $p$ methods, then the use of such a method degrades to a lower error order. But you are looking for the maximal order of a method, which is used when classifying a method, or which you will get with empirical methods like stepsize-error plots (loglog). I believe that that point is too obvious to be mentioned explicitly.